# Unable to create table in mysql while referencing

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

```
CREATE TABLE `DB`.`ORDER` (
    `oid`               INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `createdAt`         TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `oValue`            FLOAT NOT NULL,
    `no`                INT NOT NULL,
    `qty`               INT NOT NULL,
    `status`            VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `refundStatus`      VARCHAR(10),
    `refundId`          INT,
    `paymentStatus`     VARCHAR(10),
    `paymentId`         INT,
    `aid`               INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(`oid`),
    FOREIGN KEY `aid` REFERENCES ADDR(`aid`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

ADDR table with key `aid` do exist in the db but I am getting error while running this command.

Error:

```
CREATE TABLE `DB`.`ORDER` (
    `oid`               INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `createdAt`         TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `oValue`            FLOAT NOT NULL,
    `no`                INT NOT NULL,
    `qty`               INT NOT NULL,
    `status`            VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `refundStatus`      VARCHAR(10),
    `refundId`          INT,
    `paymentStatus`     VARCHAR(10),
    `paymentId`         INT,
    `aid`               INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(`oid`),
    FOREIGN KEY `aid` REFERENCES ADDR(`aid`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REFERENCES ADDR(`aid`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 14
```

I am not able to figure out why in this case it is happening and not in other case.

Comment: need parens around the foreign key columns  `FOREIGN KEY (aid) REFERENCES`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
FOREIGN KEY `aid` REFERENCES ADDR(`aid`)
```

with:

```
FOREIGN KEY (`aid`) REFERENCES ADDR(`aid`)
```

or with the official *standard SQL* syntax:

```
constraint fk1 FOREIGN KEY (`aid`) REFERENCES ADDR (`aid`)
```

Comment: I didn't notice bracket in my other queries. Thanks a bunch